# Module Not Found When Run on Docker-Compose

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm preparing a Dockerfile that will be used in production. But for some reason, the last command is returning an error.

```
react_1  | [WEBPACK] Building 1 target
react_1  | [WEBPACK] Started building bundle.[chunkhash].js
react_1  | [WEBPACK] Build failed after 33.631 seconds
react_1  | [WEBPACK] Errors building bundle.[chunkhash].js
react_1  | Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in '/home/app/react/src'
```

Here is the copy of the docker file

*Dockerfile.prod*

```
FROM node:7.10.1-alpine

RUN apk update
ENV HOME=/home/app
COPY . $HOME/react/
RUN npm install yarn -g

WORKDIR $HOME/react
RUN mkdir build && mkdir dlls && yarn

CMD ["yarn", "start:prod"]
```

Here's the copy of the `docker-compose` file

*docker-compose.prod.yml*

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  react:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - 3100:3100
    volumes:
      - /home/app/react
```

When I `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build -d` it works as expected until when it builds the webpack file. But fails as you can see in the error above.

But when I do this `docker-compose run react yarn start:prod` the webpack builds just fine.

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/abarcenas29/react-sandbox/tree/wip/docker-improvements) in question.

Comment: I am getting same error for start:dev and start:prod `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in '/home/app/react/src'`

Comment: try `import { App } from './App';`  - instead of `import App from './App'`... expecially where `export default class App`

Answer (score 4):

My bad. It was case sensitive errors. Since I was on windows it just went through without problems.

So the error happened because the `import` statement was finding `App` folder, but the actual folder was `app`.